# .net core identity server Api call 401 return to login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm new with identity server 4 i have most part figured out except 1:

inside 1 of my controller (page) i am making a call to an API, if this return me a 401 how can i redirect to the login page with a return URL of my current action. (I'm using .net core 2.0).

i already tried:

```
public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";
        String token = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;

        WebRequestResult<List<string>> result = WebRequest.SecureGet<List<string>>(
                "http://localhost:52426",
                new List<string> { "application/json" },
                "/api/Values",
                token,
                new Dictionary<string, string>()                    
            );

        if (result.ResultStatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(async () => {
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");

            }));

        }
        return View();
    }
```

which redirect me only to the logout page which is not what i need.

Comment: Is this authentication just for the `Contact()` method, or there are more methods you need to protect?

Comment: Hi, the contact() method call my api, in my test case scenario my API will not be authentificated yet and will return a 401, which is want i want. From that I am looking on how to retrieve the Login URI and redirect there (Identity login uri)

Comment: Can you use the logout action in the account controller to send the user where you need?

Comment: Instead of implementing this manually for the `Contact()` method, have you tried configuring the middleware, e.g. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Startup.cs to redirect to login page with return URL set?

Comment: Hi, yes i tried to create a custom return URL which is not working.

Comment: Have you tried using AuthenticationProperties class when calling the SignOutAsync method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.0